# ASP.NET MVC beginform not calling controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send a string from a form to a Controller, but clicking the submit button doesn't send anything to the ActionResult.

Instead, it's returning an error 404. I have tried it with HttpPost and HttpGet, but both don't work.

Here is the Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ExistingClient()
    {
        ViewBag.Existing = true;

        return View("LandingPage");
    }

    public ActionResult SearchClient(string q)
    {
        var client = from p in identityDb.MyUserInfo select p;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
        {
            client = client.Where(x => x.NIP_Regon.ToString() == q);
        }

        ViewBag.FoundClient = true;
        ViewBag.Name = client.ToList().First().FirstName;

        return View("LandingPage");
    }
```

And my views:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LandingPage";
}

<h2>Wystaw fakturę VAT dla</h2>

<br /><br />

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group .col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Istniejący klient", "ExistingClient", "Vat", new AjaxOptions(), new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Nowy klient" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>

    @if(ViewBag.Existing == true)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.Partial("_GetClientPartial")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Partial:

```
@model Stacja_paliw.Models.UserInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_GetClientPartial";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchClient", "Vat", "FormMethod.Get"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <h4>Podaj NIP klienta</h4>

        <div class=".col-md-12">
            @Html.TextBox("q", null, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "client-search", @placeholder = "Client NIP" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Wyślij" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" />
        </div>

        @if(ViewBag.FoundClient == true)
        {
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Name);           
        }

    </div>
}
```

And default route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchClient", "Vat", FormMethod.Get))` - no quotes around `FormMethod.Get`

Comment: Try to write HttpPost method for 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchClient(string q)
    {
} . it will hit to you controlelr. Also make sure that you BeginForm has correct syntax  as @StephenMuecke mentioned.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchClient", "Vat", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "search-client-form"}))

You need to make FormMethod.Post and no quotes around it.